# Dismiss notification from BroadCastReceiver

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I have a subclassed BroadCastReceiver inside my main activity in an android application to deal with changing the GUI when a GCM comes in.  All of this works fine.

The one thing that doesn't work is that if this gets called then the user has my app open on his device, and as such I want to clear the notification I entered into the notification center for this incoming GCM.  If I put the cancelAll() and cancel(int) lines into my GCMIntentService, then it dismisses the notifications, but I cannot keep it there since I only want to dismiss this notification if the user has my app open.  I used both the cancel() and cancelAll() to make sure that I wasn't somehow passing the wrong notification id from the IntentService (I have verified it is correct).

The problem is that there is no error and the notification in the notification center simply won't go away.  I have verified that this method is getting called since I get the log entries in logcat.

I referenced this prior answer, but it doesn't work in my implementation for some reason: [Starting and stopping a notification from broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765465/starting-and-stopping-a-notification-from-broadcast-receiver)

My code inside my main activity:

```
private class NotificationBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v("Push", "Received Push Notification!");

    //Now that the user has opened the app, cancel the notification in the notification center if it is still there
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    final int NOTIFICATION_ID = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId",0);

    Log.v("NOTIFICATION_ID",Integer.toString(NOTIFICATION_ID));

    mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    mNotificationManager.cancelAll();

    Log.v("Canceled Notifs","Canceled");
  }
}
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Firstly Put a log after `cancellAll` an check if you are getting the log in there. Secondly, have you tried the scenario on other device?

Comment: Added it and here is a transcript:

08-13 12:40:45.387: I/Push Notification(30615): Completed work @ 826126803\r\n

08-13 12:40:45.387: V/Push(30615): Received Push Notification!

08-13 12:40:45.387: V/NOTIFICATION_ID(30615): 1

08-13 12:40:45.387: V/Canceled Notifs(30615): Canceled

Comment: I haven't tried this on other devices yet - Could this really be a device issue?  My testing is being done on a new Nexus 5 running API version 20 os 4.4 kitkat

Comment: One possibility is that you are firing another notification in other part of your application right after dismissing previous ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A potentially better option is, instead of posting the notification while the app is open, to first detect if the app is visible and, if it is, don't display the notification. You can do this using `Intent` broadcasts or an event bus like EventBus or Otto.

Example:

```
public class GCMReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // this is your receiver after gcm has been received 
        Intent appOpenCheck = new Intent("com.example.IS_APP_OPEN");
        // put extras about your notification here...
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(appOpenCheck);
    }
}

public class AppNotOpenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // this is your receiver that will be hit if the app isn't open 
        // post your notification to the NotificationManager
    }
}
```

Then, in `AndroidManifext.xml`:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".AppNotOpenReceiver">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.IS_APP_OPEN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Finally, in your `Activity`:

```
BroadcastReceiver appOpenAlert = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        abortBroadcast(); // prevents notification from going further
        // this is your receiver that will be hit if the app is open 
        // update your ui
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    IntentFilter notificationReceived = new IntentFilter();
    notificationReceived.addAction("com.example.IS_APP_OPEN");
    notificationReceived.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
    registerReceiver(appOpenAlert, notificationReceived);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    unregisterReceiver(appOpenAlert);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: For anyone finding this answer - I was able to make it work as stated, with a couple of minor changes.  The main one is that after setting the priority of the receiver in the main app to higher than the "AppNotOpen" receiver, you must include a call to abortBroadcast() inside the main app receiver or it will propagate to the "AppNotOpen" after the receiver in the main app handles it per the ordered broadcast and will still add the notification as was not desired.

Comment: And I just noticed that I missed this call to abortBroadcast() in your original response, sddamico.  Good solution, and thanks again!

Comment: Think I may have updated after the original post to add that, but regardless, glad I could help. Been a problem I've dealt with a few times now.