# How to cancel a Notification when RingerMode changed

Tags: android, notifications

Im Trying to make a status bar notification that notifies when the app is active and the notification cancels when the app is inactive.
I have got the notification to notify when the user turns the app on by clicking the on button within the app. I have also got the notification to cancel when the user switches the app off in the same way. 
the problem i have is that the user can switch the app just by turning up the ringer volume, but the notification does not cancel when the app is turned off in this way.
Im getting the error:

```
System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

MainActivity:

```
buttonToggleDetect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        // when the main button is clicked
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setDetectEnabled(!detectEnabled);
            mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                    .setCategory("Home")
                    .setAction("Share")
                    .build());

            if (isServiceRunning()){
                showStatusBarIcon("App","App Active",true);
            }
            else showStatusBarIcon("App","App InActive", false);
        }
```

.

```
public void showStatusBarIcon(String notificationTitle, String notifactionMessage, boolean serviceActive){
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.info_icon,"App Active",System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent notifactionIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notifactionIntent,0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(MainActivity.this, notificationTitle, notifactionMessage, pendingIntent);
    if (serviceActive) {
        notificationManager.notify(9999, notification);
    }
    else {
        notificationManager.cancel(9999);
    }
}
```

RingerModeStateReceiver class

```
public class RingerModeStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

public RingerModeStateReceiver() {
}

@Override // when the android sends a broadcast message that the RingerModeState has changed
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving


    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);


    int ringMode = audioManager.getRingerMode();
    if (ringMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL){
        context.stopService(new Intent(context, CallDetectService.class));
        mainActivity.showStatusBarIcon("App","App InActive", false);
    }
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

can anyone see help me, see where i'm going wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From another post i found the answer.
In the Broadcast Receiver class,I replaced

```
mainActivity.showStatusBarIcon("App","App InActive", false);
```

with

```
 NotificationManager notifactionManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifactionManager.cancel(9999);
```

Heres a link to 
[answer in other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765465/starting-and-stopping-a-notification-from-broadcast-receiver)

I searched "how to cancel notifaction from broadcast" to find the post

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the notification before your closing the app.

You can do it from the onDestroy of the app or even from the service.

The problem is that "showStatusBarIcon" can't be called from the broadcastReciever you need to use the context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. how would i go about giving it context?

Comment: You already got it in the BroadcastReceiver you can try: 'context.MainActivity.showStatusBarIcon(....)'